# Swapping bits at a given point between two bytes

Tags: bit-manipulation, genetic-algorithm

Let's say I have these two numbers:

```
x = 0xB7
y = 0xD9
```

Their binary representations are:

```
x = 1011 0111
y = 1101 1001
```

Now I want to crossover (GA) at a given point, say from position 4 onwards.

The expected result should be:

```
x = 1011 1001
y = 1101 0111
```

Bitwise, how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

I would just use bitwise operators:

```
t = (x & 0x0f)
x = (x & 0xf0) | (y & 0x0f)
y = (y & 0xf0) | t
```

That would work for that specific case. In order to make it more adaptable, I'd put it in a function, something like (pseudo-code, with `&`, `|` and `!` representing bitwise "and", "or", and "not" respectively):

```
def swapBits (x, y, s, e):
    lookup = [255,127,63,31,15,7,3,1]
    mask = lookup[s] & !lookup[e]
    t = x & mask
    x = (x & !mask) | (y & mask)
    y = (y & !mask) | t
    return (x,y)
```

The lookup values allow you to specify which bits to swap. Let's take the values `xxxxxxxx` for `x` and `yyyyyyyy` for y along with start bit `s` of 2 and end bit `e` of 6 (bit numbers start at zero on the left in this scenario):

```
x        y        s e t        mask     !mask    execute
-------- -------- - - -------- -------- -------- -------
xxxxxxxx yyyyyyyy 2 6                   starting point
                              00111111  mask = lookup[2](00111111)
                              00111100       & !lookup[6](11111100)
                      00xxxx00          t = x & mask
xx0000xx                                x = x & !mask(11000011)
xxyyyyxx                                  | y & mask(00111100)
         yy0000yy                       y = y & !mask(11000011)
         yyxxxxyy                         | t(00xxxx00)
```

Comment: It's not obvious that a LUT is better than `(1<<s) - (1<<e)`.  And BTW, you can swap bits with only 3 XORs + 1 AND: see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

**If a bit position is the same in both values, no change is needed in either.  If it's opposite, they both need to invert.**

XOR with 1 flips a bit; XOR with 0 is a no-op.

So what we want is a value that has a `1` everywhere there's a bit-difference between the inputs, and a 0 everywhere else.  That's exactly what `a XOR b` does.

**Simply mask this bit-difference to only keep the differences in the bits we want to swap**, and we have a bit-swap in 3 XORs + 1 AND.

Your mask is `(1UL << position) -1`.  One less than a power of 2 has all the bits below that set.  Or more generally with a high and low position for your bit-range: `(1UL << highpos) - (1UL << lowpos)`.  Whether a lookup-table is faster than bit-set / sub depends on the compiler and hardware.  (See @PaxDiablo's answer for the LUT suggestion).

```
// Portable C:

//static inline
void swapBits_char(unsigned char *A, unsigned char *B)
{
    const unsigned highpos = 4, lowpos=0;  // function args if you like
    const unsigned char mask = (1UL << highpos) - (1UL << lowpos);

    unsigned char tmpA = *A, tmpB = *B; // read into locals in case A==B

    unsigned char bitdiff = tmpA ^ tmpB;
    bitdiff &= mask;               // clear all but the selected bits
    *A = tmpA ^ bitdiff;           // flip bits that differed
    *B = tmpB ^ bitdiff;
}

//static inline
void swapBit_uint(unsigned *A, unsigned *B, unsigned mask)
{
    unsigned tmpA = *A, tmpB = *B;

    unsigned bitdiff = tmpA ^ tmpB;
    bitdiff &= mask;               // clear all but the selected bits
    *A = tmpA ^ bitdiff;
    *B = tmpB ^ bitdiff;
}
```

([Godbolt compiler explorer with gcc for x86-64 and ARM](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5AHoZggkwJ5kAajwsGGzBwAMAQQBuqPOlWCA7kwAOPQoID6yBE2IQRLQXmAtMZ566qAFT6pKoeXj5%2BqgHEwTwAlHr6HADsfAaqWTGongThnt6%2BZgjeCNaogqocAMwAIqoALGEMqBYVgrV1urU8WXKqAGYeyMq5qq7AVXiDqgCeoqpaANY6mdloeQWRxTEucQC2TILL1fWqELQAqgAyZwDCtfeqpcDllQmqALQX13dPTyWbQ6SRqGRS6yyESK0ViqgIB2s%2BjODRCYQRthR8V6qgGxEwTDMGiIQOQTAY0xYMWOmFUKXqXXByWy2xh/n2qgARoR8INZl14YjkRwAKzYQW2XrM7Lcgi8/lcABsAqOJxxLI1GoGyAYBLi5IYXJE%2BQICFpgkwutG0VlnUhwWF5wxwrFXJ5M0G6s12QGgy01jdBCqpqUqnlmHx6GlWSCfQFGLjrtl8qlBjSdWSyTkCiUKnUmm0yWMpnMVlshAcImJ7kKUTMaNZdfiYWhTdVyySafS0cbu2dWIbCYHfDBmftrd2yY9WP7ovFCdTyJl7r51SVKuOyy93q1MhiusCBqNJrN5ktmGtZltPZCM6F1STK89o/tsbvmLngZTL5SqQzaYMAYLEIBBRBPWkDkwA4SDmVRUGsQQwioEQFFUfFgDwBQIztIwTDMTAAA8CBrHY/FICc/FBcFizMSwbDsAgHHQzCCGwki2QlUJe2iBMW1rXZ207X9wRZCiryfd8XXnRERxE5c5WnbhlXOdtFxZWcxQFKc%2BTU7IhznLSn10rJCOI510Rkqj%2Bj3RQ8AYMkGENYDTVUQxXCqBQ7MNDQJmIYAvmsY4vDYNDMAwrDiBw9NkikBJGGkEUpFIFhpF0JLUGkR5eH4cxRHEWluBqWgkoIVLYri5YQBqAAOAA6VJGlSGpGkVXRUi4WhqsVarmgYaRGiSlKpDS0gMqkJLBBAXRSFK4bYtIOBYCQNBETsiNyEoFbrDW4gQGAar6EGOzWMiyhOTK0huRYVw5mkYrSBWyCWAIAB5TRbrm0gsCONhdQu/B8VGPBDEwSbPsIi9jUkKR7uJS0LoIYg8AOO75uYNgUH4fhGDwTlJsgOL4LGTxpC%2BAi1C%2BBQo3qHwRFoWhvgAdSPL5GdM4gmG%2BF6agmvKJDoOK%2BqkRLkousaCK6r5FUaVRgGQNQ6oZiBcEIEg1yKsJ7lQVbdTiQraE%2BLK%2BF4EqyoSCqqtoWrWoATloIqbd0EURV0RUahFRV4qkAbSBR2hdGmoaRrGiappms2FpgRAUG17bdY2iAtp2kBXAOVJ/dII6GBOyaIHOz6rpu1GHu1p7Xve/6oNYYA/s%2BgGL2UEGwZGiHkCh4u4aFkbEeR1HBerzHst4HG8fgQnrGJsGyYp5nHKZ9nOa%2BbnebEfmDa9kWg/S6R9AAJQAWVl%2BXVFSWquFqpWWFyTBPmV/AiD1rgNdULWdYjdWuENrGTfDubzdISqXAbbW0aO7LgXBdDgJqK7aqXsfZ%2BwDqLT6IchBh1mmlf%2BQsuBJQQYHMW0hTZ/ziiDSKeBcggEaEAA%3D))

This is **not an xor-swap**.  It does use temporary storage.  As [@chux's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45361419/c-swap-a-bit-between-two-numbers/45362168#45362168) on a near-duplicate question demonstrates, a masked xor-swap requires 3 AND operations as well as 3 XOR.  (And defeats the only benefit of XOR-swap by requiring a temporary register or other storage for the `&` results.)  This answer is a modified copy of my answer on that other question.

This version only requires 1 AND.  Also, the last two XORs are independent of each other, so total latency from inputs to both outputs is only 3 operations.  (Typically 3 cycles).

---

For an x86 asm example of this, see this code-golf [Exchange capitalization of two strings in 14 bytes of x86-64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166012/exchange-capitalization/166520#166520) (with commented asm source)

Comment: Related: [How to use bitwise operations to assign specific bits of a byte according to two other bytes? (bit blend according to a mask)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68049722) to just blend according to mask.

Answer (score 0):

[**Swapping individual bits with XOR**](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingBitsXOR)

```
unsigned int i, j; // positions of bit sequences to swap
unsigned int n;    // number of consecutive bits in each sequence
unsigned int b;    // bits to swap reside in b
unsigned int r;    // bit-swapped result goes here

unsigned int x = ((b >> i) ^ (b >> j)) & ((1U << n) - 1); // XOR temporary
r = b ^ ((x << i) | (x << j));
```

Comment: That swaps two (non-overlapping) bitfields within one `unsigned int`.  There's only one input (`b`) and one output (`r`).  It's not a helpful starting point for a masked xor-swap of corresponding bits between two values.