# C - Swap a bit between two numbers

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

I just tried with this code:

```
void swapBit(unsigned char* numbA, unsigned char* numbB, short bitPosition)//bitPosition 0-x
{
    unsigned char oneShift = 1 << bitPosition;

    unsigned char bitA = *numbA & oneShift;
    unsigned char bitB = *numbB & oneShift;

    if (bitA)
        *numbB |= bitA;
    else
        *numbB &= (~bitA ^ oneShift);

    if (bitB)
        *numbA |= bitB;
    else
        *numbA &= (~bitB ^ oneShift);
}
```

to swap bit position x of a and b but because of the if() I think there's something better.

Also when i see this:

```
*numbB &= (~bitA ^ oneShift);
```

I really think that there's an easier way to do it.
If you have something for me, i would take it :)

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't really "swap two bits of a number" is it, more like "swap the a bit between two numbers" or something, that's still a confusing description though..

Comment: Step 1: When working with unsigned types, better to use `1u << bitPosition`  (add `u`)

Comment: Thanks, harold, I modified the title, i didn't mind it.... Chux, i'll use that now, thanks :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First you should set the corresponding position in a number to `0`, and then OR it with the actual bit, removing all of the conditions:

```
*numbB &= ~oneShift; // Set the bit to `0`
*numbB |= bitA;      // Set to the actual bit value
```

The same for the other number.

Comment: Very nice ! Thanks you a lot

Answer (score 2):

A single bit is no easier than an arbitrary bitmask, so lets just talk about that.  You can always call this function with `1U << bitpos`.

**If a bit position is the same in both values, no change is needed in either.  If it's opposite, they both need to invert.**

XOR with 1 flips a bit; XOR with 0 is a no-op.

So what we want is a value that has a `1` everywhere there's a bit-difference between the inputs, and a 0 everywhere else.  That's exactly what `a XOR b` does.  Simply mask this to only swap some of the bits, and we have a bit-swap in 3 XORs + 1 AND.

```
// call with  unsigned char mask = 1U << bitPosition; if you want
inline
void swapBit_char(unsigned char *A, unsigned char *B, unsigned char mask)
{
    unsigned char tmpA = *A, tmpB = *B; // read into locals in case A==B

    unsigned char bitdiff = tmpA ^ tmpB;
    bitdiff &= mask;               // only swap bits matching the mask
    *A = tmpA ^ bitdiff;
    *B = tmpB ^ bitdiff;
}
```

([Godbolt compiler explorer with gcc for x86-64 and ARM](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAKxAEZSAbAQwDtRkBSAJgCFufSAZ1QBXYskwgA5AHoZAamRMGDeQHdCCefJEtBeYC0zpFCJsXkBbJoIDW8jgGYAIvNoBVB44DCT7/IAjQgAFVH0CPFQWJx55PAAzeQBPUXVWAg4ABgBBOTwWBnzMLOyAN1Q8E0E1JgAHHkIAfWQzYghdfUNjU3N5ACps0h09AyMTFt6%2BgWHOsZ6LazsAShKOAHY%2BHO1tDtHuiYsCS1rsr1cBoaP6s/6%2BR03T7d2u8dbAwnx4xKdXK9OOACs2HkVzuD227wIn2%2BXAAbD8rDZbDEIai0XJFAxML1lKoAiICCCEJh5IJMFjkARukECBBBCsttsMQBJZwAaXUCCS8mAyGQ8kKtkwghBqAFqCYJimII0EgAdCUIQMbn8HEDIdCYorttKEaC1cCaZr7qs1s5VjlypVSTV6k0RPlac85hcZnspdNnd1FrYGdl1uCniMXiDjv8XP1BqHrgiplrGTtg3MjQlvhHVYDgaD449tCmvg44QifSi0WX5BjkFicSpAgSiSSyRSqSYaXS/Urw78wwaNamc0rYnrjkP1fn4jn1uaciUZH1tBjWKgCMSLDVuUR5EwrSZlHgbPlgCUdza6g0CFx2kn9m8%2BsRhQRiHhKfIo17XpN74JH8/CZ7rx%2BCxIn6Abaomsw3r0443Mqma3AO2zQdw8IRiW9zlhhlbVhYuJ1oSK6NuSmCUtShDtmBkYGgi44IdoupAtRHz9iaM5miUfQyLOChmCKm73gwEoenELCKDYJIEaSRD3qKlGWBgCR4N0hDyBA/ouD8PB%2Bie1Rnk01hJHuNhXhBgGRkM77zLc5kAZZPogRsFEWQcfYFrG/zqnGLG5i5MIoa4aGxBhZZYdiOG1vi%2BHEqSREka2ZH0hRsEMRGNFeYOVEpUxXyTmxM6WhUJiYAAHk6AGkO%2BKxedptrno097AHg36YMQgjGe60ZvjZoLWSZiLLKagbge1SHpj2cHZmliFZb5xZIrRHUZa4qWDdGo7YIxULMStxW0n8lwjpVgUYgQTB4AwSi1hoK7yKU5git%2BZ2qPkW7EMAAC0tQ2PobDyPVjVUi1prTtkUhLIw0gAlIpAsNImRQ6g0i%2BLw/CkqI4gktwji0FDBCw6DYO2CAjgABxymsAAsayOOTsKZGsXC0MTsLE%2BT4NSOTUMw1IcOkAjUhQ4IICZKQuPc6DpBwLASBoMcZ3NeQlAy7UcvECAwBU6Q8RnQDgsQAEeOkEELDmEk0jY6QMuWJgLAEAA8gUpti6QWDWGwWIG/g96UngpTCgbxXEQSkhSObjrkgbP6WGb4vMGwKD8PwjB4AEguQGDqC1BEUSC1Ib1Ffyb3fugPyGCItC0PIb0AOq4dXO3EEwle244AtoxIdBgwwEOcwbfNFUzb2wuTPJ8vIaxyo4Km4IQJCFljQzeKgstYhYmO0Es8hI3wvA43jSwE0TtByrTACctBYyfmQAgCmSwo4AKwmzHOkFHtCZMLXM83zAtCyLe8SzARAKAl7KxXgrCASsVYgHMJYNYb9Nba2arrfWTsjYm2jhbJeVsbb2wYI7HmLtWDAHdk7T2xEIi%2BxzjzAOyAg4YLDl3J2kdo6dyIfHZGvAk4p3gOnTOkQ9DSDzgXGutY64lQbk3FuQg26SHXmzSG0Ne7SGyAAJQALIj35OPLgcoK4QBYFETAG8IDTyknPegm8QEqznlwDeW9%2BC7zFvvUghMuAn2PuTe%2BXAuCZG8Y4W%2BxMn5Q1fu/RRTtv5CF/qLOGzjGFcGCXQUJn94bSEcTEsGvsWr8JAOTIAA%3D), includes a version with `unsigned` instead of `unsigned char`.)

You could consider `if(bitdiff) { ... }`, but unless you're going to avoid dirtying a cache line in memory by avoiding the assignments, it's probably not worth doing any conditional behaviour.  With values in registers (after inlining), a branch to save two `xor` instructions is almost never worth it.

This is **not an xor-swap**.  It does use temporary storage.  As @chux's answer demonstrates, a masked xor-swap requires 3 AND operations as well as 3 XOR.  (And defeats the only benefit of XOR-swap by requiring a temporary register or other storage for the `&` results.)

This version only requires 1 AND.  Also, the last two XORs are independent of each other, so total latency from inputs to both outputs is only 3 operations.  (Typically 3 cycles).

---

For an x86 asm example, see this code-golf [Exchange capitalization of two strings in 14 bytes of x86-64 machine code](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/166012/exchange-capitalization/166520#166520) (with commented asm source)

Comment: A micro optimization for a weak compiler could use `bitdiff = (*A ^ *B) & mask; *A ^= bitdiff; *B ^= bitdiff;` which is like the result of the "This version only requires ..." paragraph.

Comment: @chux: Writing to `*A` before doing `*B ^= bitdiff` is not equivalent in a stand-alone function when it's not know that `A != B`.  Check the godbolt link for the code-gen different with the `_mayalias` version (named that because gcc has to reload `*B` after the write to `*A`.)

Answer (score 1):

Form the mask

```
unsigned char mask = 1u << bitPosition;
```

And then earn the wrath of your peer group with [XOR swap algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XOR_swap_algorithm).

```
*numbA ^= *numbB & mask;
*numbB ^= *numbA & mask;
*numbA ^= *numbB & mask;
```

Note this fails when `numbA == numbB`.

Comment: I wanted to give it as an alternative, but remembered the wrath of the SO peers on one of recent questions ☺️

Comment: @EugeneSh. IMO, it is the `numbA == numbB` problem that ultimately rejects this approach as it is a surprising error.

Comment: @EugeneSh.: `*numbB & mask` already needs temporary storage somewhere so it can be an operand for XOR.  (Unless you're on a machine with ternary booleans, like x86 [AVX512F `vpternlogd`](http://felixcloutier.com/x86/VPTERNLOGD:VPTERNLOGQ.html).)  So a masked xor-swap defeats the only advantage of xor-swap (at an asm level): no extra register.  I posted an answer with 3 XOR and only 1 AND.  (I think the bit-difference technique was fairly well known; I've seen it before but hadn't previously fully grokked it.)  Anyway, it's *far* better than the OP's branchy version.