# Making a bitwise choose box in MIPS

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mips, bitwise-operators

Similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62014238/majority-box-in-mips-assembly?noredirect=1#comment109682455_62014238)

I realized that what I am trying to do can be done mostly with bitwise operators, no need for complicated loops or messing with the stack, so that's what I am trying to do now.

Now I need to make a choose box that works as follows:

It chooses the bits based on the value of input E (32 bit integer). If a bit of E=1, the output bit is the corresponding bit of F (another 32 bit integer). If a bit of E is 0, the output bit is the corresponding bit of G. In this way, the bits of F and G are shuffled together based on the value of E.

I guess I could make this with a loop but is there a simpler way like in the link?

Comment: Bitwise operations like `or` do all 32 bits in parallel; that's the entire point.  If you can express the formula for one bit as a boolean expression like `majority = (A&B) | (B&C)`, you can use the same operation on 32-bit integers to get 32 results in parallel, one in each bit of the result.  For bit blend, see [Merge bit sequences a and b according to a mask](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39282691) - the formula is in the question

Comment: Also related: [C - Swap a bit between two numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45361419)/ / [Swapping bits at a given point between two bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839334).  Just blending into one is slightly simpler than swapping; you leave out the step that would calculate the other result.

Comment: In general for any boolean function of any number of inputs, you can write down a truth table and start looking for boolean operations that can implement it.  It's always possible to implement any boolean truth table of N inputs in terms of MIPS's AND, OR, XOR, and NOR operations, it's just a matter of finding an efficient sequence.

Comment: e.g. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/digital/chpt-7/converting-truth-tables-boolean-expressions/ shows a way to derive boolean expressions from truth tables, then simplify them down to something reasonable.

Comment: @PeterCordes Riiight, I remember that from Digital Systems in the first semester. Hadn't seem the connection.

Comment: @PeterCordes I'm a bit rusty on this stuff. I am trying to make a Karnaugh map for this. I figure it's going to look a bit like a multiplexer but it's confusing me. Can you give me some clues?

Comment: @PeterCordes I think I got it. Is it (G&!E) || (F&E)? If so it's almost the same as the other one

Comment: Yes that's one way to blend.  But in C notation `!` is logical NOT, producing a boolean 0 or 1 result for the whole integer, not per-bit.  `||` is also logical OR, not evaluating the right hand side if any bits in the left are set.  In C it would be `(G & ~E) | (F & E)`.  Another way to optimize it might involve `(F^G) & E`, then XOR that info F or G.  MIPS doesn't have an ANDN instruction so `G & ~E` would take two instructions, not one.

Comment: @PeterCordes I did this `la $t0,E`
`la $t1,F`
`la $t2,G`
   
   
`and $t1,$t1,$t0 #(F&E)`
`not $t0,$t0  #!E`
`and $t2,$t2,$t0 #(G&!E)`
   
`or $t0,$t1,$t2 #(G&!E) || (F&E)`

Probably a bit clumsy.

Comment: @PeterCordes You have used ^in other posts, what does it mean exactly? Not power I assume.

Comment: You're still writing your comment with broken notation.  Bitwise NOT is `~` not `!`, bitwise OR is `|` not `||`.  You want arithmetic (bitwise) operators, not logical (whole value as one boolean): https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/expressions.  Also, you didn't load values, only addresses; you only used `la` not `lw`.

Comment: I'm using C notation, as linked in my last comment.  `^` is XOR.  Many other language use the same conventions as C for bitwise booleans, including Java, Javascript, Python.  https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_arithmetic

Comment: @PeterCordes Right. Fixed that. Thanks again.