# How to Replace the MSB bit with some Number in Assembly language?

Tags: assembly, arm, stm32f4

I have an task to generate an Random numbers in assembly language just like rand function in c Language but in assembly language i had to extract the B0,B5,B6 bit from the 8 bit data number and perform the following tasks on that bit

1. EOR B5 and B6
2. EOR B0 and result of (B5 ^ B6)
3. And result of task 2 will be replace to MSB bit of the 8 bit data.

I've done the first 2, but can I replace the MSB bit with the result of task 2?

Comment: ARM may have a bit-field insert instruction to replace a bit without the usual AND to clear the old value and ORR to set a new 0 or 1 value.  Otherwise do that.  The linked duplicate includes an implementation of setting a `newbit` at a given position in an existing value.

Comment: That C Q&A had over-complicated looking expressions.  I'd recommend https://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#MaskedMerge to merge the low bits from the old value with the high bit from another register, as per the other two Q&As I added links to.  My answer on [Swapping bits at a given point between two bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50839334) explains the details of how the masked xor bitdiff trick works to implement a bit blend.  (Or a bit swap if you apply it both ways).